# Read array from Firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I have a collection defined in Firebase with different field types, such as Strings and arrays of string.

I am able to read Strings from `DocumentSnapshot` simply by calling:

```
String name = document['name'];
```

But how can I get `List<String>`? By calling

```
List<String> names1 = document['names'];
List<String> names2 = document['ingredients'].map((x) => x.toString())
```

I get following exceptions accordingly:

> type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'
>   type 'MappedListIterable' is not a subtype of type 'List'

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808513/how-do-you-load-array-and-object-from-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/50867881#50867881

Comment: I wouldn't call it a duplicate, as I am trying to get an array, not an object, but I found the answer there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It could be done simply using a named [`.from`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/List/List.from.html) constructor:

```
List<String> names = List.from(document['names']);
```

Comment: What if array currently not exists

Comment: Using this exact code on a DocumentSnapshot document:      type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Comment: @Bisclavret I think you defined somewhere the type of your `document` as `Map<String, String>` and this is why you have this error. Try this `List<String> names = List.from(document['names'] as Iterable<dynamic>);`

Comment: If array currently not exists you can provide an empty array: ```List.from(document['names']??{});``` @AbdullahKhan