# Flutter: Lazy Load data from firestore

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Note: I have already seen answers on Lazy Load of ListView but those are for custom API not firestore database!

I have a books summary app, App fetches data from my `Firebase/Firestore` database and then display it using a `ListView.builder` which is wrapped inside a `StreamBuilder`.

Now, I want to fetch data lazily, I mean as the user scrolls through the List the required data gets loaded rather than loading data at once and then displaying it lazily.

```
//The Widget used to display data:

Widget feed() {
  return Container(
    width: deviceWidth,
    height: deviceHeight / 3,
    child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('feedItem')
            .orderBy('feedId', descending: true)
            .snapshots(),

        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            int totalLength = snapshot.data.documents.length;
            return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: totalLength > 10 ? 10 : totalLength,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  width: deviceWidth / 2.5,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) => FeedIntro(
                                  snapshot.data.documents[
                                      ((totalLength - 1) - index)]['feedId'])));
                    },
                    child: Card(
                        child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          // width: 150,
                          height: 150,
                          foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                    snapshot.data.documents[index]['feedImage'],
                                  ),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                        ),
                        Center(
                            child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['title']),
                        )),
                      ],
                    )),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Sorry Something went wrong!'));
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
              ),
            );
          }
        }),
  );
}
```

Comment: What you call "lazy loading", many others call "pagination".  Firestore has that capability.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Comment: To add to @DougStevenson comment you could pair that with the flutter firestore API (as I think the firebase team has yet to add Dart examples) from here: https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/startAfterDocument.html

Also, these methods were recently added to the Dart firestore plugin (the incomplete API of the dart implementation is likely *why* the team has yet to add dart examples). :)

Comment: Thanks for giving your time! I got it I can use either limit or startAfter to fetch data in pieces but any suggestion on what approach I should use to integrate, this with my current code (StreamBuilder and ListView.Builder)?

Comment: @RajDhakad got any solution yet?

Comment: @ShrutiRamnandanSharma as far as I remember, all the data from firestore is cached, so after the first time(when it's not cached), it will automatically be fetched lazily.

Comment: So @RajDhakad, what's the solution of it?

Comment: Nothing, it will work automatically the data from firestore did get load lazily in a listview.

Comment: @RajDhakad but My problem is different of your's . please look at the this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58935132/why-is-it-consuming-much-time-to-retrieve-data-from-firestore-with-flutter/58948985?noredirect=1#comment104402578_58948985). Please help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 7):

The description of your lazy loading seems to match what pagination is. Here's a simple demo using Firestore with pagination in a `ListView.builder`

This sample implements snippets from Firebase official doc for [Firestore pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query).

There are two ways to load the data on the view in this demo.

- Refresh the entire `ListView` using
  [`RefreshIndicator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html)
- Scroll down to hit the bottom of the list to load up the next documents in the `ListView`.
  [`ScrollController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html)
  is used to determine if the user has hit the bottom part of the list.

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'DocObj.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Initialize Firebase
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDocuments();
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.atEdge) {
        if (scrollController.position.pixels == 0)
          print('ListView scroll at top');
        else {
          print('ListView scroll at bottom');
          getDocumentsNext(); // Load next documents
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: listDocument.length != 0
            ? RefreshIndicator(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: scrollController,
                  itemCount: listDocument.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text('${listDocument[index].documentName}'),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                onRefresh: getDocuments, // Refresh entire list
              )
            : CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<DocObj> listDocument;
  QuerySnapshot collectionState;
  // Fetch first 15 documents
  Future<void> getDocuments() async {
    listDocument = List();
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('sample_pagination')
        .orderBy("name")
        .limit(15);
    print('getDocuments');
    fetchDocuments(collection);
  }

  // Fetch next 5 documents starting from the last document fetched earlier
  Future<void> getDocumentsNext() async {
    // Get the last visible document
    var lastVisible = collectionState.docs[collectionState.docs.length-1];
    print('listDocument legnth: ${collectionState.size} last: $lastVisible');

    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('sample_pagination')
        .orderBy("name").startAfterDocument(lastVisible).limit(5);

    fetchDocuments(collection);
  }

  fetchDocuments(Query collection){
    collection.get().then((value) {
      collectionState = value; // store collection state to set where to start next
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        print('getDocuments ${element.data()}');
        setState(() {
          listDocument.add(DocObj(DocObj.setDocDetails(element.data())));
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

To parse the data inside the document, you can create a model for your object.

```dart
class DocObj {
  var documentName;

  DocObj(DocObj doc) {
    this.documentName = doc.getDocName();
  }

  dynamic getDocName() => documentName;

  DocObj.setDocDetails(Map<dynamic, dynamic> doc)
      : documentName = doc['name'];
}
```

The sample handles this data from Firestore.

[image: firestore dashboard]

Here's how the app looks when running.

[image: demo]

Comment: ```ListView.builder``` does the work. A beginner mistake is adding ```ListView.builder``` in a ```SingleChildScrollView``` which tries to load everything at once making the ```ListView.builder``` useless or sometimes loading the data directly into a ```SingleChildScrollView```. I hope this comment helps some beginners.

Comment: Is there a way to show loading at the end ?

Comment: The author is asking for loading data with pagination with realtime data from a snapshot stream. You are just fetching chunks of data here with loosing the capability to get realtime updates.

Answer (score 2):

I have suffered this,and what i did is i have added scrollcontroller in listview builder and i traced if it reaches bottom of the list and if it reaches at the bottom,then update the limit of the snapshot.

I have experimented this and works well.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  ScrollController _chatScrollController;
  int loadMoreMsgs = 25; // at first it will load only 25
  int a = 50; // 'loadMoreMsgs' will added by 'a' if we load more msgs in listview.
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    _chatScrollController = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        if (_chatScrollController.position.atEdge) {
          if (_chatScrollController.position.pixels == 0)
            print('ListView scrolled to top');
          else {
            setState(() {
              loadMoreMsgs =  loadMoreMsgs + a;
            });
            print('ListView scrolled to bottom');
          }
        }
      });
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CollectionName').limit(loadMoreMsgs).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(
          controller: _chatScrollController,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text('This is a sample');
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have only written required codes for understanding.