# Why is it consuming much time to retrieve data from firestore with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

first,I added an animation, after animation completed I called below code line but it's consuming too much time.

```
getData()async{
 DateTime now = DateTime.now();
       await Firestore.instance.collection('Table_Name').getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot){

        print("length ${snapshot.documents.length}");
        for(int i = 0 ; i< snapshot.documents.length; i++){

          bool isToday = snapshot.documents[i].data['CreatedBy'].toString().split(" ")[0]==DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(now);
          print("isTOday $isToday");
          if(isToday && snapshot.documents[i].data['GainStatus']== "0"){
            setState(() {
            giftDocumentID = snapshot.documents[i].documentID; 
            });
            break;
          }
        }
        winOrLose(now);
        print("giftDocumentID: $giftDocumentID");
      });
}
```

This Above codes taking approx 10 min to retrieve data from firestore,  Why is it too lazy?

Comment: Do not fetch all the documents of your collection all at once. This could impact the response time depending on the size of your document. Fetch the data only you need, try limiting the query using where. Its worth taking a look at https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/08/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-query-slow.html

Comment: But I've just 12 documents in my database , it should not take too much time.

Comment: if it is just 12 documents it shouldn't, its worth clearing the app's cache and retrying.

Comment: Yep! I cleaned and was working perfect  for the first time , but in next time, same issue still facing.

Answer (score 0):

It got solved by testing it on another device and running smoothly without any much time consumption. 
Actually my first device's memory has filled, so that's why, taking too much time.

But I'm still confuse, what the relation between device's memory space and firestorm database..!

Comment: the data you download by querying is cached in your device for offline usage.

Comment: If I delete cache memory then will it be run smoothly ?

Comment: sure , I have faced the same issue in one query action and I notice my device almost out of charger :) so he reduce the process and power , the device power is important to handle what you do but please define the Collection reference out side function and clean any code maybe make duplicate or make query less if you make more then one query

Comment: setState will rebuild so maybe your code will redefine your collection reference and another code already defined

Comment: So sir, I should need define Collection reference as globly ?

Answer (score 0):

The relation between firestore data and device's memory is cache. When data is loaded for the first time, it's from firebase's servers (and thus costs you read requests), then firestore saves the data in the cache memory for future use. So slow retrieval of the data must be a Device OS problem (or a power issue).

You can remove caching feature from firebase data but I won't recommend that.

Also as suggested earlier you should not load all data at once especially if the data is going to be fetched a lot or data gets changed very often. The solution for that is pagination.

This Video explains Flutter Pagination nicely:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coR4Y-DkrLc