# Lazy Loading list view builder in Flutter with Helper.Provider-Model

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore, lazy-loading

what I'm trying to do is use lazy loading of elements in list view builder in flutter.
I used also the Provider, helpers and model paradigma and I'm trying to load some dishes from my db in firestore.

I found different solution for implementing lazy loading such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411802/flutter-lazy-load-data-from-firestore). But I obtain an error.

Below the code:
Helpers

```
class DishServices{
  String collection = "dishes";
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String subcollection = "ingredients";
  List<DishModel> dishes = [];
  QuerySnapshot collectionState;

  Future<List<DishModel>> getLazyDishes() async
  {
    var collectionData = _firestore.collection(collection).orderBy("name").limit(2);

    fetchDocuments(collectionData);
    return dishes;
  }
  Future<List<DishModel>> getLazyDishesNext() async {
    // Get the last visible document
    var lastVisible = collectionState.docs[collectionState.docs.length-1];

    var collectionData = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(collection)
        .orderBy("name").startAfterDocument(lastVisible).limit(3);

    fetchDocuments(collectionData);
    return dishes;
  }


  fetchDocuments(Query collection){
    collection.get().then((value) {
      collectionState = value; // store collection state to set where to start next
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
          dishes.add(DishModel.fromSnapshot(element));
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Provider

```
class DishProvider with ChangeNotifier{
  DishServices _dishServices = DishServices();
  List<DishModel> dishes = [];
  List<DishModel> dishesLazyNext = [];


  DishProvider.initialize(){
    _loadDishes();
//    searchIngredient(ingredientName:"cime");
  }

  _loadDishes() async{
    dishes = await _dishServices.getLazyDishes();
    notifyListeners();
  }
  Future loadNextLazyDishes()async{
    dishesLazyNext = await _dishServices.getLazyDishesNext();
    dishes = dishes + dishesLazyNext;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Main.dart

```
oid main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: DishProvider.initialize())
  ],
      child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'MyApp',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.red,
          ),
          home: ScreensController()
      )));
}
```

Finally my build is :

```
class _MainHomeState extends State<MainHome> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final dishProvider =  Provider.of<DishProvider>(context);
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.atEdge) {
        if (scrollController.position.pixels == 0)
          print('ListView scroll at top');
        else {
          print('ListView scroll at bottom');
          dishProvider.loadNextLazyDishes(); // Load next documents
        }
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dishProvider =  Provider.of<DishProvider>(context);


    //atest.loadA();
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            
            OtherElement(),
            
            Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  itemCount: dishProvider.dishes.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (_,index){
                    return DishWidget(
                      dishModel: dishProvider.dishes[index],
                    );
                  }),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

this is the error that return when I try to run the app

How I can fix it?

[image: Error when I run the app]

Answer (score 0):

Just move the scroll listener to your `build`:

```dart
class _MainHomeState extends State<MainHome> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dishProvider =  Provider.of<DishProvider>(context);

     scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.atEdge) {
        if (scrollController.position.pixels == 0)
          print('ListView scroll at top');
        else {
          print('ListView scroll at bottom');
          dishProvider.loadNextLazyDishes(); // Load next documents
        }
      }
    });


    //atest.loadA();
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            
            OtherElement(),
            
            Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  itemCount: dishProvider.dishes.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (_,index){
                    return DishWidget(
                      dishModel: dishProvider.dishes[index],
                    );
                  }),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


}
```