# Flutter/Dart casting from Firestore into map

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have problems with mapping data from firestore into a model. 
I've been trying for hours and always getting cast errors (exceptions) like *'Map can't be cast to Map'* or 'type *'_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'Map'*

I tried examples from these links:

[How do you load array and object from Cloud Firestore in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808513/how-do-you-load-array-and-object-from-cloud-firestore-in-flutter)

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36836

and many more, still don't understand how this thing works.

Here is my entity and model class:

Entity

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class ScreenHomeEntity extends Equatable {
  final String id;
  final String userName;
  final String userEmail;
  final String mainDoor;
  final Map<dynamic, dynamic> doors;

  const ScreenHomeEntity(
      this.id, this.userName, this.userEmail, this.mainDoor, this.doors);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id, userName, userEmail, mainDoor, doors];

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'ScreenHomeEntity {id: $id, userName: $userName, userEmail: $userEmail, mainDoor: $mainDoor, doors: $doors}';

  Map<String, Object> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'userName': userName,
      'userEmail': userEmail,
      'mainDoor': mainDoor,
      'doors': doors,
    };
  }

  static ScreenHomeEntity fromJson(Map<String, Object> json) {
    return ScreenHomeEntity(
      json['id'] as String,
      json['userName'] as String,
      json['userEmail'] as String,
      json['mainDoor'] as String,
      json['doors'] as Map<dynamic, dynamic>,
    );
  }

  Map<String, Object> toDocument() {
    return {
      'userName': userName,
      'userEmail': userEmail,
      'mainDoor': mainDoor,
      'doors': doors,
    };
  }

  static ScreenHomeEntity fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return ScreenHomeEntity(
      doc.documentID,
      doc.data['userName'],
      doc.data['userEmail'],
      doc.data['mainDoor'],
      doc.data['doors'],
    );
  }
}
```

Model:

```
import 'package:brava_flutter/data/entities/screen_home_entity.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

@immutable
class ScreenHome {
  final String id;
  final String userName;
  final String userEmail;
  final String mainDoor;
  final Map<String, ScreenHomeDoor> doors;

  ScreenHome(this.userName,
      {String userEmail = '',
      String id,
      String mainDoor,
      Map<String, ScreenHomeDoor> doors})
      : this.userEmail = userEmail ?? '',
        this.id = id,
        this.mainDoor = mainDoor ?? '',
        this.doors = doors ?? Map<String, ScreenHomeDoor>();

  ScreenHome copyWith({
    String id,
    String userName,
    String userEmail,
    String mainDoor,
    Map<String, ScreenHomeDoor> doors,
  }) {
    return ScreenHome(
      userName ?? this.userName,
      id: id ?? this.id,
      userEmail: userEmail ?? this.userEmail,
      mainDoor: mainDoor ?? this.mainDoor,
      doors: doors ?? this.doors,
    );
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode =>
      id.hashCode ^
      userName.hashCode ^
      userEmail.hashCode ^
      mainDoor.hashCode ^
      doors.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is ScreenHome &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          id == other.id &&
          userName == other.userName &&
          userEmail == other.userEmail &&
          mainDoor == other.mainDoor &&
          doors == other.doors;

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'ScreenHomeModel {id: $id, userName: $userName, userEmail: $userEmail, mainDoor: $mainDoor, doors: $doors}';

  ScreenHomeEntity toEntity() =>
      ScreenHomeEntity(id, userName, userEmail, mainDoor, doors);

  static ScreenHome fromEntity(ScreenHomeEntity entity) {
    return ScreenHome(
      entity.userName,
      id: entity.id,
      userEmail: entity.userEmail,
      mainDoor: entity.mainDoor,
      doors: entity.doors, // EXCEPTION
    );
  }
}

class ScreenHomeDoor {
  String name;
  String address;

  ScreenHomeDoor.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data)
      : name = data['name'],
        address = data['address'];
}
```

firestore data example:
[image]

Comment: You miss some of the code, but I see possible errors with types incompatibility.

Didn't you forget to use your `ScreenHomeDoor.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data)` method?

Can you show your Firestore object structure from the firebase console?

I can help you if I understand how do you plan convert your

`Map<dynamic, dynamic>` to `Map<String, ScreenHomeDoor>`

Comment: I added picture from firestore (data structure).
I didn't forget to call .fromMap (ScreenHomeDoor), I'm calling it with 'fromEntity' in model class, that is where I'm getting the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

in model, method 'fromEntity' I didn't cast entity map (dynamics) to model map (object) which is exactly where exception occurred.
Every "value" from this dynamic map should have been transformed to object, which I was doing wrong all the time.

```
  static ScreenHome fromEntity(ScreenHomeEntity entity) {
    return ScreenHome(
      entity.userName,
      id: entity.id,
      userEmail: entity.userEmail,
      mainDoor: entity.mainDoor,
      doors: entity.doors
          .map((k, v) => MapEntry(k as String, ScreenHomeDoor.fromMap(v))),
    );
  }
```

for the whole time I was trying to do it with `MapEntry(k as String, v as ScreenHomeDoor.fromMap(v))`

A simple and stupid mistake....