# is there a way to generate model class for firestore database on Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently manually doing this process. This is a sample data class. Is there a way to generate automatically?

```
class RideModel {
  final String docId;
  final bool hasRequest;
  final String rideCollectionId;
  final String vehicleTypeId;
  final double corporationRate;
  final double driverRate;
  final double driverInsurance;
  final double passengerInsurance;
  final List startUpCharge;
  final double waitingCharge;
  final double normalCharge;

  RideModel({this.docId, this.hasRequest, this.rideCollectionId,this.vehicleTypeId, this.corporationRate, this.driverRate, this.driverInsurance, this.passengerInsurance, this.startUpCharge, this.waitingCharge, this.normalCharge});

  factory RideModel.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    var data = doc.data;

    return RideModel(
        docId: data['docId'],
        hasRequest: data['hasRequest'],
        rideCollectionId: data['rideCollectionId'],
        vehicleTypeId: data['tripDetails']['vehicleType']['vehicleTypeId'],
        corporationRate: data['tripDetails']['vehicleType']['corporation'].toDouble()??0.0,
        driverRate: data['tripDetails']['vehicleType']['driver'].toDouble()??0.0,
        driverInsurance: data['tripDetails']['vehicleType']['driverInsurance'].toDouble()??0.0,
        passengerInsurance: data['tripDetails']['vehicleType']['passengerInsurance'].toDouble()??0.0,
        normalCharge: data['tripDetails']['vehicleType']['normalCharge'].toDouble()??0.0,
        startUpCharge: data['tripDetails']['vehicleType']['startUpCharge']??[],
        waitingCharge: data['tripDetails']['vehicleType']['waitingCharge'].toDouble()??0.0);
  }
}
```

Comment: there are several packages available for json to model conversion. why don't you search on pub dev?

Comment: Interesting, I wish there were one, same here coding all manually.

Comment: Look at this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json . This may help you.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @Alex Sunder Singh on the comments and in one of the answers to this [Community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808513/how-do-you-load-array-and-object-from-cloud-firestore-in-flutter), you can use [JsonSerializable()](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) to do it.

In order to use it, you must set these dependencies on you pubspec.yaml

```yaml
dependencies:
  # Your other regular dependencies here
  json_annotation: <latest_version>

dev_dependencies:
  # Your other dev_dependencies here
  build_runner: <latest_version>
  json_serializable: <latest_version>
```

Then, add the `@JsonSerializable()` annotation to you class as well as importing the package to you class, it would look something like this

```dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class RideModel {
  final String docId;
  final bool hasRequest;
  final String rideCollectionId;
  final String vehicleTypeId;
  final double corporationRate;
  final double driverRate;
  final double driverInsurance;
  final double passengerInsurance;
  final List startUpCharge;
  final double waitingCharge;
  final double normalCharge;

  RideModel(this.docId, this.hasRequest, this.rideCollectionId,this.vehicleTypeId, this.corporationRate, this.driverRate, this.driverInsurance, this.passengerInsurance, this.startUpCharge, this.waitingCharge, this.normalCharge);

  factory RideModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$RideModelFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$RideModelToJson(this);
}
```

NOTE: use `@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)` if you want all of your non-primitive objects to be described as json and not as 'Instance of Object'

Finally, generate the JSON serialization code by running the code generation utility from your terminal

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

With that you will be able to use `toJson()` to map data to you object and `fromJson()` to send your object as data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I prefer using an online tool... https://app.quicktype.io/
It may be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **VS Code** you can also just do **⌘ + .** (Mac) and then click **"Generate data class"** this automatically generates a toJson and fromJson method based on the properties of the class.

If you have **nested** data these objects should also have a fromJson and toJson and so the "Generate data class" command can automatically use them in the fromJson and toJson method.

This way you don't need any external tool.

Comment: It might be helpful to share that it's required to install this extension for that to work: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BendixMa.dart-data-class-generator. Thanks.