# Flutter firebase, List<dynamic> is not of type List<String>

Tags: firebase, flutter, types

While assigining data from firestore

`List<String> idList = snap.data['idList']`

I get the error

`List<dynamic> is not of type List<String>`

The `idList` in firestore looks like so

[image: <code>idList</code> array in firestore]

Comment: Please provide sample of data.

Comment: can you provide screenshot of idList in firestore ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to use `List.castFrom`

```dart
List<String> idList = List.castFrom(snap.data['idList'] as List ?? []);
```

the `as List ?? []` is not mandatory, but prevents error if data is undefined or null.

Comment: this worked for me but what if i want to add list of strings to firestore, how would i do that