# looping inside a list in dart flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve a list from firebase then to print all list contents.
I tried the classic for loop but it's showing me an error I guess my approach isn't correct

this is my code

```
body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .doc("list_instructors")
          .collection('Instructor')
          .where('Email', isEqualTo: email)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.separated(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  Divider(height: 1),

              // ignore: dead_code
              itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                List courses = doc['Courses'];
                return ListTile(
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
                  selectedTileColor: Color(0xffE5E5E5),

                  title: Text(
                    for(i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
                     courses[i].toString() 
                    },
                    style: GoogleFonts.asap(
                      fontSize: 22,
                      color: const Color(0xff455e89),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
```

[image]

this is my current output im able only to retrieve one element from my list in firbase.

this is the list, i want all list content to be printed
[image]
how do i do it without the for loop ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the error message you get.

Comment: Additionally if you could show some sample output vs some expected output, I'm having a little trouble putting together what you want the code above to do. Should it show a text widget inside a ListTile for every course taught by a particular professor? Or a single text widget inside a single ListTile with all of the courses taught by a particular professor?

Comment: i just updated my post please check it .

Comment: and yes every course taught by particular professor

Comment: Can you try changing the line `List courses = doc['Courses'];` to `List<String> courses = List.from(doc['Courses']);` and see if it works?

Comment: this also is showing me the first element in the list

Comment: Can you try changing the line `List courses = doc['Courses'];` to `List<String> courses = List.castFrom(doc['Courses'] as List ?? []);` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62357148)?

Comment: Does the above change resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `courses` is not read properly as a `List`.

instead of this line:

```
List courses = doc['Courses'];
```

try this:

```
var coursesListFromJson = json['Courses'];
List<String> courses = (coursesListFromJson != null) ? coursesListFromJson.cast<String>() : null;
```

Comment: when i tried your code it showed This error: operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'JsonCodec'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.