# How to map data from Firestore to a list and convert to object data type

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to map data from firestore `QueryDocumentSnapshot` type into an `Object` of a custom `Class` but no success

Here is my class

```
class Food {
 String name;
 int price;
 String image;

  Food({this.name, this.price, this.image, });
}
```

the example down below i made the data locally and fetching it works fine

```
     List<Food> foodType1Local = [
        Food(
          name: 'Food 1',
          price: 10,
          image: 'assets/food1.png',
        ),
        Food(
          name: 'Food 2',
          price: 20,
          image: 'assets/food2.png',
        ),
        Food(
          name: 'Food 3',
          price: 30,
          image: 'assets/food3.png',
        ),
      ];
     List<Food> foodType2Local...
     List<Food> foodType3Local...
```

the example down below i made the data in cloud firestore and fetching it is a problem

[image]

the example down below i am getting data from cloud firestore but i get error `type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Food'`

```
  List foodType1Cloud = <Food>[];
  List foodType2Cloud = <Food>[];
  List foodType3Cloud = <Food>[];

  getFoodType1Cloud() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("foodType1").get();
      foodType1Cloud.addAll(snapshot.docs);
      foodType1Cloud.map((foodType1Data) {
        Food(
          name: foodType1Data['name'], //cant do --> name: foodType1Data[index]['name'],
          price: foodType1Data['price'], //cant do --> price: foodType1Data[index]['price'],
          image: foodType1Data['image'], //cant do --> image: foodType1Data[index]['image'],
        );
      }).toList();
  }
  getFoodType2Cloud()...
  getFoodType3Cloud()...
```

here is the main body of the code if i try fetching from **local data** it works fine but does not work when i fetch from cloud firestore

```
   //tabs of length "3"
   body: TabBarView(
     children: [
       Container(
         margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
         child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             buildFoodList(foodType1Local),
           ],
         ),
       ),
       Container(
         margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
         child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             buildFoodList(foodType1Loca2),
           ],
         ),
       ),
       Container...
       
     ],
   ),
```

here is the main body of the code again but if i try fetching from **cloud firestore** it shows error `type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Food'`

```
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  buildFoodList(foodType1Cloud),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  buildFoodList(foodType2Cloud),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container...

          ],
        ),
```

I thought the `buildFoodList` code would be necessary as well so i added it just incase

```
Widget buildFoodList(List foods) {
    return Expanded(
      child: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: foods.length,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 0.8,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return FoodCard(foods[index]);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `snapshot.docs` returns an array of all the documents in the `QuerySnapshot` and obviously it's not a type of `Food`.

Now, you have to iterate over the array of documents and use the `data` member that gives all the data of this snapshot. Using that data you could convert it to any type of instance you wish.

So, instead of this

```js
foodType1Cloud.addAll(snapshot.docs);
```

You can convert the document content into your custom object and add it to the list

```js
snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
   Map<String, dynamic> obj = doc.data;
  // convert this Map to your custom object and add it to your list
});
```

In flutter, you can use [json_serializable](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) for this conversion!

similar SO ref - [How do you load array and object from Cloud Firestore in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808513/how-do-you-load-array-and-object-from-cloud-firestore-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:

```
class Employee {
  Employee(this.employeeID, this.employeeName, this.branch, this.designation, this.location,
      this.salary,
      {this.reference});

  double employeeID;

  String employeeName;

  String designation;

  String branch;

  String location;

  double salary;

  DocumentReference reference;

  factory Employee.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    Employee newEmployee = Employee.fromJson(snapshot.data());
    newEmployee.reference = snapshot.reference;
    return newEmployee;
  }

  factory Employee.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _employeeFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _employeeToJson(this);

  @override
  String toString() => 'employeeName ${employeeName}';
}

Employee _employeeFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
  return Employee(
    data['employeeID'],
    data['employeeName'],
    data['branch'],
    data['designation'],
    data['location'],
    data['salary'],
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _employeeToJson(Employee instance) {
  return {
    'employeeID' : instance.employeeID,
    'employeeName': instance.employeeName,
    'branch': instance.branch,
    'designation': instance.designation,
    'location': instance.location,
    'salary': instance.salary,
  };
}
```

Step 2:

Pass the AsyncSnapShot and build the Data as List

```
List<Employee> employees = [];

Future<void> buildData(AsyncSnapshot snapshot) async {
    if (snapshot.data.documents.length == 0) {
      employees = [];
    }

    employees = [];
    await Future.forEach(snapshot.data.documents, (element) {
      employees.add(Employee.fromSnapshot(element));
    });
  }
```